# Private Messages between Agent and supervisor

Tags: community, liveagent

In live agent set up we have an option for private messages between Supervisor and Agent which means if an agent raised a flag to supervisor then supervisor reacts to that an he messages to Agent,if agent send reply to that message it is showing to both supervisor and external user(chat requested user).Is there a way to set messages sending by agent to supervisor as private(means chat requested user no need to see that).

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, as of now, this only works one way (Supervisor to Agent).